# Добавить точку в конец строки

Tags: php

```
<div>

<p>Правила подфорума и Безопасность сделок</p>

</div>
```

тегов в div может быть много и разных, подскажите как добавить точку к последнему слову 
`сделок.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если точка уже есть, то можно так

```
$text = '<p>Правила подфорума и Безопасность сделок</p>';

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~<p>(.+)</p>~iu',
    function ($a) {
        return (substr($a[1], -1) != '.' ? '<p>'. $a[1] .'.</p>' : $a[0]);
    },
    $text
);
```

Comment: @Solo_777, таким образом, возврат результата будет зависеть от условия.

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно это вам необходимо?

```
$text = '<p>Правила подфорума и Безопасность сделок</p>';

echo preg_replace('~<p>(.+)</p>~iu', '<p>$1.</p>', $text);
```

Comment: спасибо. а как сделать  если точка уже есть, то ещё одна не добавлялась ?